# matlab calling matlab over tcp/ip

Tags: matlab, tcp

Is it possible for a Matlab version N, xx bits function running on machine A to call a Matlab version M, yy bits function on machine B?  Where N may or no be equal to M, xx may or not be equal to yy, and A may or not be the same as B.

Or. more low level, is it possible to pack Matlab data types into network order strings and send them over tcp/ip to another Matlab instance where it would be unpacked into the proper data type?

Using the Java engine and sending/receiving everything over JSON?

Calling out to C/C++/.NET transporting over that layer and then calling in on the other side?

Comment: This is pretty broad, what do you want to "call" on the instance on machine B to do? If you just want it to run something then that's a simple system call, if you want them to interface and share data (akin to a parcluster with 1 node) then you're likely going to need to write a custom intermediary layer.

Comment: Let's say a non Matlab program loads the MCR via a dll.  It then wants to call functions a and b, that are defined in two Matlab instances, A and B, possible running on other computers.  It would do that by calling remote_call (machine, function, param1, ..., paramN) on the local MCR, wich would then call function(param1, ..., param2) on the given machine.  Then do the same when machine A and machine B are running Matlab generated .exes, with some kind of intermachine/proc layer, say gRPC.

Comment: You'll find more exact answers if you ask more exact questions... there's too much supposition and hypothetical here to give a good answer